# Sumar dos primeros digitos y si dan un resultado de dos digitos o más sumar los siguientes dos

Tags: python

```
def strycomprovar(s):
    result = str(s)
    for c in result:
        if c >= "0" and c <= "9":
            finalresult += c
    return finalresult
def condense(s):
    result = 15
    i1 = 0
    12 = 1
    while result <= 10:
        result = strycomprovar(s)[i1] + strycomprovar(s)[i2]
        i1 += 1
        i2 += 1
    return result
```

Me da un error de que int es intinerable.
Un ejemplo de la función seria:
print condense(524a4)

Comment: Creo que falta código. Mira que la primera línea de `condense` es `result = 15` y luego la condición del while es `while result <= 10:`, pero entre medias no editas `result` para nada, así que ese `while` nunca ejecutaría. Cuando arregles eso, tienes otros errores. La tercera línea de `condense` es `12 = 1`, probablemente sea `i2 = 1`, luego, en `strycomprovar` no inicializas `finalresult`, deberías inicializarlo antes de poder hacer `finalresult += c`.

Comment: No puedes invocar `codense(524a4)` pues `524a4` no es un dato válido. Si quieres que sea un número hexadecimal, debes usar `0x524a4`, pero tal como tienes el código, que no acabo de entender, más parece que lo quieres tratar como cadena, en cuyo caso sería `condense("524a4")`. Por otro lado, no parece que el codigo esté preparado para esa "a" entre los dígitos, pues parece que esperas sólo dígitos de 0 a 9

Comment: Algo que puede ayudar es que intentes describir mejor lo que quieres hacer. En el título lo describes, pero pon más detalle en la pregunta, quizá podemos ayudarte mejor, o darte otras ideas. Y ya que pones un ejemplo de llamada `condense(524a4)` (que como dice @abulafia no funcionaría), pon el resultado que esperas de esa llamada.